# python portable matplotlib.gif no such file or directory

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I have Python Portable 2.7.5.1 on my USB (every option installed, including Matplotlib), and whenever I try to run a script with a Matplotlib code, I get this:

```
TclError: couldn't open "*path*\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-    
packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.gif": no such file or directory
```

The mentioned `matplotlib.gif` file is in the specified directory, 
    so I don't know what to do to make it work...

Comment: Are you trying to save a picture when the error arrises? Also, what's in `*path*`? Any variables like `~` or `$HOME` will not work while saving via path string.

Comment: It seems like this is a package problem.  This is the file it is trying to find: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/images/matplotlib.gif

Comment: @adrianus
I'm not trying to save anything, just trying to display a random graph...
path is just the path to the folder where my Python portable is located on my USB - here is the full path: 
    H:\Final\New portable\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.gif